# XAMPP and Thunderbird conflict

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Whenever I open Mozilla Thunderbird while XAMPP server is running an error message **'Apache HTTP Server has stopped working'** is keeps popping up (and it does disconnects localhost access).

I suspected it could be a port conflict issue because the error message stops when I close Thunderbird and both of them use same port 25. So I tried to change 25 to 26 in Thunderbird and tried to change Apache Server port to 444 from 443 since Thunderbird also use port 443 (as Apache access.log given below).

I updated conf, sendmail.ini and php.ini files accordingly. But both of them failed. I've given the complete error message below.

```
Apache HTTP Server has stopped working
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.12.0
  Application Timestamp:    54c90386
  Fault Module Name:    php5apache2_4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.5.24.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   552ec2da
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00003510
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

## My resources information:

PHP Xampp = 5.5.24

OS = Windows 7 64bit

## Xampp Service Settings:

### Ports

Apache2.4 = 80, 443

Mercury = 25, 79, 105, 106, 110, 143, 2224

### httpd.conf:

Listen 80

### sendmail.ini:

smtp_server=localhost

smtp_port=25

### php.ini:

[mail function]

SMTP = localhost

smtp_port = 25

sendmail_from = root@localhost

### Thunderbird

In four of my accounts in Thunderbird client, two accounts using 587 as port and two localhost accounts using 25.

accountname1: root@localhost
accountname2: root2@localhost

Server Name: localhost

Port: 110

### Apache access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jan/2016:10:12:31 +0530] "CONNECT live.mozillamessaging.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 2895 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/38.4.0"
```

### Apache error.log

```
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:16.193174 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00428: Parent: child process 5220 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:17.464707 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:17.555531 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:17.558460 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:17.558460 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:17.570180 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4776
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:18.864175 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4776:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:19.241142 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4776:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:19.328060 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4776:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:21.809600 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00428: Parent: child process 4776 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:23.011795 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:23.140706 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:23.141683 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:23.141683 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jan 01 11:27:23.153402 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5884
```

Comment: I've changed it. Now no error message arises. But I couldn't connect localhost.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I just tried it and got access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Change port to 85
> >
> > Access **localhost by accessing like this `localhost:85/`**